# Confused about s3c_nand.c and s3c2410.c in the Linux kernel source

Tags: linux-kernel

Currently I am porting Linux kernel to a `s3c6410` based development board, so I referred to `mini6410`, `real6410` Linux kernel source, when it comes to the `Nand Flash driver`, I found `s3c_nand.c` file in `drivers/mtd/nand/` which seems to be written by `Samsung`, however when I checked the official Linux kernel source, I can only find `s3c2410.c` file even in the newest version.

So my question is why `s3c_nand.c` is not included in the Linux kernel source and what is the difference between `s3c_nand.c` and `s3c2410.c`, or can I use `s3c2410.c` for my `s3c6410`board?

Comment: To find the difference (or if they even have comparable purpose) you'd probably have to examine the files or talk to whoever created the pory you are interested in.  As for why something would be in a vendor tree and not in a mainline kernel release, that's quite common - patches don't get into the mainline kernel until someone goes to the trouble of formally submitting them in a form that meets with the maintainers' approval, in both little details and major architectural approach.

Comment: But I think s3c6410 is an old and popular architecture, and Linux kernel must have complete support for it without the vendor patch, so s3c2410.c should provide the ability to use Nand Flash in s3c6410 boards, is it right?

Comment: Many vendors write the code for a particular SOC hardware.  Then, it is found that various hardware is 95% the same and small conditionals can handle multiple SOC systems (NAND flash controllers).  So *s3c_nand.c* maybe a driver that handles the *s3c2410* and other controllers.  Look at the source, the Kconfig and any documentation.

Comment: But s3c_nand.c is not included in the kernel source officially, however, s3c2410.c is included since a very old version, so I guess maybe s3c2410.c is responsible for the Nand Flash driver of all s3c SOCs.